# problem with how to do thread and Makefile

Tags: c, multithreading, makefile

I made this short makefile but when I launch it from the terminal it comes back:

```
 cc project.c -o project
/ usr / bin / ld: /tmp/ccNEO5PL.o: in function `main ':
project.c :(. text + 0x29c): undefined reference to `pthread_create '
/ usr / bin / ld: project.c :(. text + 0x2f0): undefined reference to ` 
pthread_join '
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: project] Error 1
```

Yet lpthread is present in the compilation ... where am I wrong?

```
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
LP = -lpthread
PT = -pthread
project: exam.o memorizer.o
       $(CC) exam.o memorizer.o

exam.o : exam.c
       $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) $(PT) exam.c $ (LP) -o exam

memorizer.o : memorizer.c
       $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) memorizer.c -o memorizer
clean:
       rm *.o project
```

Comment: You have to add `-pthread` to the compile line, and also to the link line.  Adding `-lpthread` (link the pthread library) to the compile line doesn't do anything because you are not linking libraries when you are compiling.  You link libraries when you're linking.

Comment: I did as you suggested but nothing has changed

Comment: Your output does not match provided Makefile. Please update your question with exact and unedited output of linking stage, including exact linker invocation.

Comment: BTW. Your compilation lines also do linking, since you have not provided `-c` flag. If you intend to create object files instead of final binaries (as suggested by the target line), you should add `-c`. Additionally, your recipes do not create objects they declare (i.e. creating `exam` instead of `exam.o`), which is inconsistent and confusing about what this is intended to do.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, could you show me how it should be done?